# Select Max in a table to get name in other table SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, max, highest

I have 2 tables

Players

```
Pnr
Pname
Padress
Pcity
```

Tickets

```
Tnr
Pnr
Date
Costs
```

I want to get the name of the player with the highest `Ticket Cost` from the database with `Select`. And I want to know who has got a `Ticket` in May. I also want to know who has never got a `Ticket`.
How do I get each of these?
Pnr is the primary key of Players and is connected with Pnr from Tickets

I've tried

```
SELECT MAX(Costs) from Players, Tickets
Where max()
```

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes I couldn't get it to work and I also couldn't find it on the internet

Comment: Pnr of Pcity table is foreign key in Players Table?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understand correctly. Try the following query. I think it will still have some errors, but you can comment them here and I will try to correct them.

```
 select top 1 Pname from Players 
    inner join Tickets on Players.Pnr = Tickets.Pnr
    where Date > 1.05.2014 and Date <31.05.2014
    order desc by Tickets.Costs
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For highest ticket cost:

   ```
   SELECT P.*,T.Tnr,T.Date,T.cost 
   FROM Players P JOIN 
        Tickets T ON T.Pnr=B.Pnr
   WHERE T.Cost= SELECT MAX(Cost) from Tickets
   ```
2. For player who never got a ticket:

   ```
   SELECT P.*
   FROM Players P LEFT JOIN 
        Tickets T ON T.Pnr=B.Pnr
   WHERE T.Tnr IS NULL
     AND T.Pnr IS NULL
     AND T.Date IS NULL
     AND T.Costs IS NULL
   ```